# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when I watch movies online.

Tags: 14.04

When I watch movies online long enough (for about 40 minutes) the system freezes. The same happens in Windows XP. There one can see that memory usage is very high and usually restarting Firefox helps. But in Ubuntu I don't see any significant increase in memory usage. Although I assume it is the same issue as in Windows XP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If that happens both in Ubuntu and XP it could be a faulty memory module. I would run a memory test (from GRUB) for a few hours, to see if it finds anything...